# Forecasting a time series with conditional variance (heteroscedasticity) using Arima

Tags: forecasting, arima, heteroscedasticity, stationarity, garch

I want to forecast a time series and have reason to believe that there are heteroscedastic errors/variance, which could be modelled with GARCH.

However, I am not really interested in modelling/forecasting the variance. I only want point forecasts.

Does it make any sense for me to use GARCH (e.g. as an ARIMA-GARCH hybrid)?
Does GARCH have any effect on the point forecasts for my time series?
Or can I still use ARIMA or another common forecasting technique (without GARCH), even though there are heteroscedastic errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the true data generating process is ARIMA+GARCH, ignoring the GARCH part and estimating only a regular ARIMA (with constant conditional variance) means estimating a misspecified model. This will yield inconsistent estimates of the ARIMA coefficients and all the consequent troubles. That means the forecasts from an ARIMA models (with a neglected GARCH part) will likely be poor.

In case you had a linear regression with GARCH errors, you would still get consistent (although inefficient) estimates of the linear regression coefficients. Unfortunately, this is not true for ARIMA+GARCH models *unless the MA part is empty (the MA order is zero)*. That is, if you have an AR+GARCH model you may ignore GARCH errors at the expense of loss of efficiency, but still get consistent AR coefficient estimates. That means the forecasts from such a model may be OK, but you could do even better if you actually accounted for the GARCH pattern in the residuals.

If the true data generating process is not *exactly* ARIMA+GARCH but could be well *approximated* by ARIMA+GARCH, similar conclusions apply.